# Java GUI - Why do the graphics glitch when the object hits the right side of the panel?

Tags: java, user-interface

This is the part of the program that isn't functioning properly. The program is supposed to generate a bunch of circles and have them move around and bounce off the sides. When it bounces off the left size, the side(r) should decrease. When it bounces off the right side, it should increase. It works fine when it hits the left side, but when it hits the right, it just grows really big really fast, and then floats away without bouncing back. Can you help me figure this out? Thanks

```
public void myMove() {
        x+=dx;
        
        if(x<=0) {
            x-=dx;
            dx*=-1;
            r = (int)(r*1.1);
        }
        if(x>=500-(r*2)) {
            x-=dx;
            dx*=-1;
            r = (int)(r*0.7);
            
        }
        y+=dy;
        
        if(y<=0) {
            y-=dy;
            dy*=-1;
            dy = (int)(dy*1.5);
            dx = (int)(dx*1.5);
            
        }
        if(y>=500-(r*2)) {
            y-=dy;
            dy*=-1;
            dy = (int)(dy*0.7);
            dx = (int)(dx*0.7);
        }
            
    }
```

Comment: I would guess the problem is if the size is 10 and it grows by 1.5 it becomes 15 and then you move it away from the right side by 1, so 4 pixels are still touching the edge. So I would guess you need to move the circle away by the size increase (5) plus the normal 1 pixel for a total of 6 pixels?

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like is happening is when your program checks if it's hitting the right wall, it and finds a collision, it updates the location of your ball again and then changes the side size (r). When it then checks again on the next iteration, it still registers that it's colliding because the size has changed but the location of the circle hasn't changed enough to stop registering the collision.
Try moving your velocity update `dx*=-1` to above your movement `d-=dx`, and also changing the wall size first. This would be my code:

```
if(x>=500-(r*2)) {
   r = (int)(r*0.7);
   dx*=-1;
   d-=dx;
}
```

This should work, but if it doesn't, let me know more specifically what the `r` variable is. This updated code should be okay either way, but I might be assuming the variable wrong.